# Buck converter only works properly when I increase the gate voltage

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, ltspice, simulation, buck

I'm currently trying to simulate a buck converter but it doesn't work like it should and I don't know why.

It should decrease the voltage from 20 V to 14 V, but I only get a few volts at the output. The output voltage increases only when I increase the gate voltage to 15 V.

Does anyone have a solution for me?

[image: Buck Converter]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using an N-channel MOSFET as a source follower <-- that requires a gate drive voltage that is several volts higher than the output voltage you desire. You can fix your simulation like this: -

[image]

So, instead of a grounded voltage drive to the gate, you apply the voltage to gate and source as shown. Of course, in reality, this can be achieved with a high-side N-channel gate driver using a bootstrap circuit. There are plenty of chips that can help here and, some of them will have LTSpice models but, if you just want to prove the concept, the circuit above will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much!! i seen this version online but was not sure if its right because it added the 5 volts to the 20 volts from the input on the gate. So my gate voltage must always be over the output voltage? how can i achieve this if for example my Nucleo which delivers only 3.3 volts pwm voltage? 
Sorry if the questions are trivial. Im new to this topic. 
by source follower you mean that the Source dont go straight to the ground like on a sepic converter?

Comment: The source is the output in a source follower and, given that the gate needs to be several volts higher than the source to properly turn the MOSFET on, the gate voltage (measured with respect to ground) has to be several volts higher than the output voltage. You need to find a "high-side N-channel MOSFET driver" to achieve this.

Comment: thank you very much. I will search for an high side switch. Is there something i can do so that the mosfet will switch with 5 V in the simulation?

Comment: @GumGum The modified circuit in my answer allows that. The pulse source (v1) is now connected between gate and source rather from gate to ground. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).